# What could cause "An operation was skipped during export because it has a wildcard action" error when publishing a service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7, biztalk, wcf-wshttpbinding

I created an Orchestration in BizTalk, which I published as a service, using the tool WCF BizTalk. This resulted in a service hosted in IIS 7. When I changed the web.config file to enable debugging, I caught the following error:

```
Message
An operation was skipped during export because it has a wildcard action. 
This is not supported in WSDL.

Contract Name:ITwoWayAsync
Contract Namespace:http://BTKPruebas.pruebaWCF
Operation Name:TwoWayMethod
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Unfair to vote this post down as it was really badly edited. Welcome to SO, @user1750811. You may find you get a better response if you post some more code, including any relevant sections of your web.config file.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know how explain that,

Comment: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/07/pubsub-sample-using-http-polling-duplex.html seems to talk about the issue you've seen

Answer (score 1):

Some googling led me to [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dca8a16b-1ed7-46a6-94fd-67a89d8c98b8/error-while-exporting-the-policy-from-a-wcf-application?forum=wcf&prof=required):

You can solve it by removing any * Charchter from ReplyAction.

> [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://www.yyyyy.com/somthing/Registration/RegistrationService/version/2.1/getCoCRecordByMemberShipID", **ReplyAction="*"**)]